# jQuery uncaught TypeError help

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Can someone shed some light for me on what this error means and how to go about debugging it. Firefox is not an option but I am using chrome. There are no errors on localhost, only when I uploaded to server. All versions are the same and all updates are the same. Tearing my hair out trying to know where to start. Many thanks

+++UPDATE+++
I have managed to some basic debugging in chrome and this seems to be causing the error,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of null
$.ajax.successfunctions.js:83
jQuery.extend._Deferred.deferred.resolveWithjquery-1.6.2.js:1008
donejquery-1.6.2.js:7168
jQuery.ajaxTransport.send.callback
```

ajax code

```
$(function() {

 $("#newint").submit(function() {

   var send = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "newintake.php",
      cache: false,
      data: send,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(msg) {
       if( msg.status === 'error') {
          $("#NI-result").fadeIn(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);
          $("#NI-result").removeClass('error');
          $("#NI-result").removeClass('success');
          $("#NI-result").addClass(msg.status);
          $("#NI-result").html(msg.message);
       }

       else {
          $("#NI-result").fadeIn(2000).delay(3000).fadeOut(2000);
          $("#NI-result").removeClass('error');
          $("#NI-result").addClass('success');
          $("#NI-result").addClass(msg.status);
          $("#NI-result").html(msg.message+msg.info);
          //location.reload(true);
          //$('#brtv-result').addClass("result_msg").html("You have successfully retrieved: "+data.boxnumber).show(1000).delay(4000).fadeOut(4000);
          $("#NI_slider").val(0).slider("refresh");
          $("input[type='radio']").attr("checked",false).checkboxradio("refresh");
          var myselect = $("select#NI_department");
          myselect[0].selectedIndex = 0;
          myselect.selectmenu("refresh");
          var myselect = $("select#NI_address");
          myselect[0].selectedIndex = 0;
          myselect.selectmenu("refresh");
          $("#NI_dd").val('').trigger("dorefresh");
       }

     },
      error:function(){
         $("#NI-result").show();
         $("#NI-result").removeClass('success');
         $("#NI-result").addClass('error');
         $("#NI-result").html("There was an error submitting the form. Please try again. If this continues to happen,<br />please inform the administrator of the site quoting ref#: 0001F");
     }
   });
   return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: How about sharing the problem code with us?

Comment: @rwilliams that is the reason for my post. I do not know where the problem is so cannot post relevant code. That is why I posted my question to ask for help in starting to debug to find the problem.

Comment: @rwilliams that post does not apply because jquery is the only libray I am using. thanks

Comment: it looks like the issue is related to an ajax request. Can you post the code for the `success:` part (or the whole `$.ajax` part)

Comment: @tarek, here is the ajax code as requested.thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're receiving means that the argument passed to the success callback of $.ajax, `msg`, is null. Therefore, when you try to access its `status` property, you get an error (because a null value cannot have any properties). If you put `console.log(msg)` in the first line of your callback this should get confirmed; you'll just see `null` printed out in the console.

All of this suggests that the real problem has to do with the ajax response, rather than your Javascript handling of that response. And this goes along with what you said about how it works fine when running from your local computer. You're experiencing some kind of server error*, and that's precisely the thing that is changing when you run it on your local computer vs. your internet server.

*"server error" in this case does not mean that your server is making a mistake, but rather that the problem lies on the server-side rather than client (browser-JavaScript) side.

So inspect the response headers from the ajax call, as well as the server-side code that runs when the call is made. If you still can't find the issue, update your question with the response headers & server-side code.

Comment: maxedison, I cannot seem to do a console.log in chrome. is this just a firebug command. thanks

Comment: No, it's a command for any browser that has a console -- even IE8 :). Here are some instructions for opening the console in Chrome: http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/webmasters-faq.html#jsexec

Comment: maxedison, thanks for link, however, I know hot open console and js debugger but not sure how to use. for example, in firebug, i would do as you suggested console.log(msg) and fb would issue the value in the console window. this doesn't seem to work that way. any links where I could perhaps get a better understanding of the console in chrome? thanks

Comment: I tried  complete: function(resp){
        alert(resp.getAllResponseHeaders());
        }  doesn't fire alert just seems to issue same error in console.

Comment: think it may have to do with the server. On wamp when i do phpinfo.php, I can see json is active. However, on the server there is no mention of json. I am using 5.1.6. is there a library I could use? thanks

Comment: it turned out 5.1.6 doesn't come with json. Installed json library and all is now well. I would like to thank you for pointing me in the right direction and for the debugging help. cheers